# How do i execute story files in specific order in serenity BDD Jbehave

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jbehave, serenity-bdd, thucydides

I Have few jbehave story files in stories folder. whenever i execute the scripts it takes in alphabetical order.

ex:
current execution

aaa.story

bbb.story

ccc.story

i want the execution to be

ccc.story

bbb.story

and skip aaa.story

is there a way to run specific stories in specific order.
in Serenity BDD + Jbehave

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Meta:](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-info.html) to tag stories/scenarios. This is useful if you want to run just subset of stories/scenarios or skip some of them.
Example:

```
Meta: @sometag

Scenario: some scenario
Given something
```

Then you can use [meta filtering](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html) and [story mapping](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/story-mapping.html) to include/exclude scenarios marked with certain tags.

You can change story file names so their lexicographical order will match order you want them to execute:

```
1_aaa.story  
2_bbb.story
3_ccc.story
```

or create separate folders:

```
a/aaa.story
a/bbb.story
c/ccc.story
```

There is more nice solution in case when you need some story to execute before another one, [GivenStories:](http://jbehave.org/reference/latest/given-stories.html) clause:

```
GivenStories: aaa.story

Scenario: requires aaa to run
Given something
```

This will first execute aaa.story then this story. You can specify several stories in `GivenStories`.

Answer (score 1):

I have some similar scenario and what i did was create a custom ThucydidesJUnitStories, in my case i needed load only the steps for each story to avoid conflicts but in your case you could add any kind of sort to your stories list. Example

```
public class CustomThucydidesJUnitStories extends ThucydidesJUnitStories   {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomThucydidesJUnitStories.class);

    private Configuration configuration;
    private List<Format> formats = Arrays.asList(CONSOLE, STATS, HTML);

    @Test
    @Override
    public void run() throws Throwable {
        List<String> storyPaths = storyPaths();
    logger.info("Total stories to run are {}", storyPaths.size());
        //HERE YOU CAN SORT THE storyPaths as you wish 
        for(String storyPath : storyPaths) {
            Embedder embedder = configuredEmbedder();
            embedder.useConfiguration(configuration());
            String storyName =   storyPath.substring(storyPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,   storyPath.indexOf(".story"));
            logger.info("Running story {}", storyName);
           embedder.useStepsFactory(ThucydidesStepFactory.withStepsFromPackage(getRootPackage() + "." + storyName,   configuration()).andClassLoader(getClassLoader()));
            embedder.useEmbedderControls(ignoreFailsEmbedderControls());
            embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Lists.newArrayList(storyPath));
        }
    }

    public EmbedderControls ignoreFailsEmbedderControls() {
        return new EmbedderControls().doIgnoreFailureInStories(true).doIgnoreFailureInView(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        if (configuration == null) {
             net.thucydides.core.webdriver.Configuration thucydidesConfiguration = getSystemConfiguration();
             configuration = ThucydidesJBehave.defaultConfiguration(thucydidesConfiguration, formats, this);
        }
        return configuration;
    }

}
```